# Where is a good place to learn more about cloud independent Kubernetes Istio ingress controller external load balancer setup?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I am currently running Kubespray configured Kubernetes clusters that I am trying to integrate Istio as an Ingress Controller, and I am trying to figure out, not how to set up the internal workings of the Istio service (which there are tons of tutorials), but how to connect the Istio Ingress to cloud agnostic load balancers to route traffic into the cluster.

I see a lot of tutorials that mention cloud specific methodologies like AWS or GCP load balancers from within Kubernetes (which are utterly useless to me), but I want a Kubernetes cluster that knows / cares nothing about the external cloud environment that makes it easier to port or create hybrid / multi-cloud environments.  I am having trouble finding information for this kind of setup.  Can anyone help point me to information about manually configuring external load balancers to link external traffic into the cluster without relying on Kubernetes cloud extensions?

Thanks for any information you can provide or references you can point me to!

Comment: Best place IMHO is official istio documentation. That's what I used myself long back to understand and setup istio on my local laptop kubernetes clster for learning **_BEFORE_** attempting anything on AWS EKS. Take a look at [Getting Started](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/) and other related docs on istio.io, they cover everything with command samples for native k8s cluster.

Comment: I should also note I am not using any cloud specific implementation like AWS EKS or GKE.  I am trying to keep everything I do cloud agnostic, but production ready (so not on laptop).